# I want fetch the Cost from PurchaseOrder but it doesn't show any results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, rest, linq

I want to fetch Cost details from another table could someone help me with the query

```
public async Task<ResultModel<IEnumerable<GetStockReportDto>>> Handle(GetStockReportListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var spec = new StockDateSpec(request._fromDate, request._toDate);
    var data = await _stockDetailsRepository.FindAsync(spec);
    var productList = await _productRepository.GetAllAsync();
    var materialDetails = await _materialInwardRepository.GetAllAsync();
    var materialHeader = await _materialInwardHeaderRepository.GetAllAsync();
    var invoiceDetails = await _invoiceRepository.GetAllAsync();
    var purchaseOrder = await _purchaseOrderRepository.GetAllAsync();

    var result = (
                    from sList in data
                    join pList in productList on sList.ProductId equals pList.Id
                    join qList in invoiceDetails on sList.RefId equals qList.InvoiceHeaderId
                    join mList in materialHeader on sList.RefId equals mList.Id
                    join poDetails in purchaseOrder on mList.PurchaseOrderId equals poDetails.Id
                    group new { sList, pList, qList, poDetails } by new { pList.Id, sList.Date.Date, qList.Rate } into g
                    select new GetStockReportDto()
                    {
                        ProductName = g.First().pList.Name,
                        OpeningQty = 0,
                        PurchaseQty = g.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Purchase).Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                        Return = g.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Return).Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                        SaleQty = -g.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Sale).Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                        RemainingQty = g.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Purchase).Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity) - (-g.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Sale).Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity)),
                        Cost = ,
                        SaleAmt = g.Sum(s => s.qList?.Rate ?? 0),
                        PaymentAmt = 0,
                        Date = g.Key.Date
                    }
                    );
```

Here In Cost I want to fetch the Sum of Amount from purchaseOrder table where purchaseOrder.Id == MaterialInward.PurchaseOrderId and MaterialInwardID ==  sList.RefId. How can I write this query?

I tried
join poDetails in purchaseOrder on mList.PurchaseOrderId equals poDetails.Id
Cost = g.Sum(s => s.poDetails.Rate)

But it doesnt show any results

Answer (score 0):

I like doing query like this

```
    var result = (from sList in data.Where(s => s.sList.Type == ETypeEnum.Purchase)
                     join pList in productList on sList.ProductId equals pList.Id
                     join qList in invoiceDetails on sList.RefId equals qList.InvoiceHeaderId
                     join mList in materialHeader on sList.RefId equals mList.Id
                     join poDetails in purchaseOrder on mList.PurchaseOrderId equals poDetails.Id
                     select new { pList = pList, qList = qList, mList = mList, poDetails = poDetails}
                 )
                 .Where(x => (x.poDetails.Id == x.pList.PurchaseOrderId) && (x.mListMaterialInwardID == xsList.RefId))
                 .GroupBy(x => new { ProductId = x.sList.ProductId, RefId = x.sList.RefId, PurchaseOrderId = x.mList.PurchaseOrderId })
                 .Select(g => new GetStockReportDto()
                 {
                     ProductName = g.First().pList.Name,
                     OpeningQty = 0,
                     PurchaseQty = g.Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                     Return = g.Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                     SaleQty = -g.Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity),
                     RemainingQty = g.Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity) - (-g.Sum(s => s.sList.Quantity)),
                     Cost = g.Sum(s => s.poDetails.Rate),
                     SaleAmt = g.Sum(s => s.qList?.Rate ?? 0),
                     PaymentAmt = 0,
                     Date = g.Key.Date
                  }
              };
```